# Authenticating User on LogIn ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have set-up a repositories class which gets the user object and I check whether the password that is being entered matches the retrieved password from the database. The password is of course hashed with some extra security measures.

I've been doing some research on the web though and I'm still a little confused how I authenticate a user after they log in. I know there is an `[Authorize]` tag for every controller/action method which basically means: Only allow the current user to access this page if they're authenticated.

I'm just having trouble understanding how to authenticate them.

This is where I am at now:

```
if (hashedPassword == user.Password)
{
    //Correct Login Details
    //Mark this user as Authenticated/Logged in
}
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4, C#.

Thank you kindly for any hints and tips and answers.

Comment: Now you have to issue the forms authentication cookie.

Comment: @Wiktor - Can you please show me some ropes? I.e. a tutorial, website, pseudo-code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very much depends on what you use as Authentication Framework.

One of the ways with `WebSecurity` is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you use SimpleMembership provider, you can use that:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && membershipProvider.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Or for older Membership provider this works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I guess I can always use the `WebSecurity` approach since it's built in. But can you tell me how that actually works? I don't see a definitive: `model.Authorize();` or a `user.Authorized` or something similar. Where in the `WebSecurity` section does it actually authorize the current user?

Comment: And what exactly do I put inside my `if` statement that I have pasted in my original post?

Comment: `WebSecurity.Login()` handles all the verifications for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: this tutorial can help http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

Comment: Ah. So simply doing: `WebSecurity.Login(user.UserName, user.Password, true);` inside my if function shall do the trick right?

Comment: it shall. And it shall return `true` or `false` depending if the authentication is successful or not.

Comment: Brilliant. Just a quick question to yourself. In what case will it fail authentication when doing `WebSecurity.Login()`?

Comment: Usual: username or password does not match. And it does not distinguish between incorrect username or incorrect password, as showing which one is incorrect is a security issue.

Comment: Hmmmm Ok. So in my case it will always be true since it's oblivious of my MySQL set-up.